# How can I call an API with user's current location on app launch in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, class, swiftui, init

I'm trying to call an API on app launch with user's current location. My current code is:

In **ContentView.swift**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var userLocation: String {
        let latitude = "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"
        let longitude = "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
        return "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var api = randomAPI(location: userLocation)

    var body: some View {
        ...
```

In **randomAPI.swift**:

```
class randomAPI: ObservableObject {
    
    init(location: String) {
        callAPI(userLocation: location)
    }
    
    func callAPI(userLocation: String) {
        ...
```

And I'm getting the error: 
**Cannot use instance member 'userLocation' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.**

I don't know where should I put the line below to initialize the randomAPI. (I actually don't even know if this is the correct way to initialize it LOL)

```
@ObservedObject var api = randomAPI(location: userLocation)
```

Could someone help me with the problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you look for that error in SO you will find plenty of solutions

Comment: You can use `.onAppear` or `.task` to set the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Joakim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) mentioned, you need to use `.onAppear`. This is due to the fact that you cannot access a property before it is set in a struct.

For your case, the code would look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var userLocation: String {
        let latitude = "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"
        let longitude = "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
        return "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var api: randomAPI?

    var body: some View {
        SomeView()
            .onAppear {
                api = randomAPI(location: userLocation)
            }
...
```

However, I don't think setting an `ObservedObject` right after the view appears is the best way to do this.

If I were you, I would remove the init method in the `rapidAPI` class:

```
class randomAPI: ObservableObject {
    func callAPI(userLocation: String) {
        ...
```

And call the `callAPI` method when the view appears:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var userLocation: String {
        let latitude = "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"
        let longitude = "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
        return "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var api = randomAPI()

    var body: some View {
        SomeView()
            .onAppear {
                api.callAPI(location: userLocation)
            }
...
```